# Get images from firebase storage and realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

So, I wanna make the user upload multiple images at the same time to firebase storage. I have done that part successfully but now I want to retrieve the images back. At first, I was uploading one image per user and save the image id to the realtime database so it was very easy to retrieve the image back by the image id. But now how can I save more than one image to the realtime database per user I can't use the same child name because it will be replaced with the old one. Any ideas??

Uploding images and setting the id on realtime database:

```
private void Fileuploader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String imageid;

        progress.showProgress(profuctadd.this,"Loading...",false);
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(profuctadd.this);
        Cursor getimage = databaseHelper.GetPath();
        int count = 0;
        while (getimage.moveToNext()){
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getimage.getString(0));
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 35, out);
            imageid = arabic.getText().toString()+"-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"_"+(count++)+"."+getExtension(uri);
            System.out.println("IMAGES UPLOADEDDDD: "+ imageid);
            String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("storeid");
            member.setImageid(imageid);
            reference.child(id).child(arname).setValue(member);
            byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
            StorageReference Ref = mStorageRef.child(imageid);
            Ref.putBytes(data)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                            //Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            //Toast.makeText(profuctadd.this,"Image uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progress.hideProgress();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(profuctadd.this,showProducts.class);
                            intent.putExtra("spec",getIntent().getStringExtra("spec"));
                            intent.putExtra("storeid",getIntent().getStringExtra("storeid"));
                            startActivity(intent);
                            DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(profuctadd.this);
                            Cursor cursor2 = mDatabaseHelper.DeleteDataOfTableImagesAr();
                            cursor2.moveToNext();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                            // ...
                            Toast.makeText(profuctadd.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

        }





    }
```

My firebase db:

[image: Firebase Database]

Comment: you can create a new node name of images inside the user node . when you are trying to save the data in it just user the push method to store.

Comment: @HasnainSabir Great idea, But can you please explain how can i use the push method and a picture of your new node in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save more than one image of specific user in images node like that.

```
DatabaseReference dr =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tL131);

 dr.child("images").push().setValue(String.ValueOf(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()));
```